# Beginner: Outputting php varibles inside html elements as values

Tags: php, html, variables, input

I have a declared html file which is then used as an include statement inside a php file.

```
<?php 
 $social_width = "50";
 $social_height = "50";
?>
```

and

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="instagram.png" width="<?php echo $social_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $social_height; ?>" style="padding-left:400px;"></a>
```

When I debug, that is to say, echo out the variables they do have the right set values. I tried using single and double quotes, escaping quotes but did not find the solution yet.

Comment: What is the issue? Values are not outputting?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Works fine. https://3v4l.org/WcZCq

Comment: The social media icon seems to be a fixed size. So if I change $social_width to 50 it still looks like its about 200px. Any changes to the variable do not get reflected in what is produced.

Comment: I fixed it. You guys were right the code -does- work. The fix was changing it from a .html file to a .php file. I got rid of the include scenario altogether. I need to keep reading how php and html mix together as I thought you could just write php like that in an html file.

Comment: _“as I thought you could just write php like that in an html file”_ - you can write PHP code into _any_ type of file, in theory - but for it to be parsed & executed, that file must be send through the PHP parser. And whether a file gets that treatment or not, is usually configured depending on file suffixes. Some web hosters have their systems configured to send `.htm(l)` files through PHP automatically, most others likely will allow to configure that, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can include variables in double-quoted strings. This means that you could write your code like this:

```
<?php
$social_width = "50";
$social_height = "50";   
echo "<a href='https://www.instagram.com'>
        <img src='instagram.png' width='$social_width' height='$social_height' style='padding-left:400px;'>
      </a>";
?>
```

Note that this only works on "double-quoted" strings. In 'single-quoted' strings the variables will not be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing wrong. But my  best guess is that you may be including the HTML file before declaring your variables. (That is including at the top). This will probably not work

Here is my sample code which works fine.

```
<?PHP
 $social_width = "50";
 $social_height = "50";


 include('1.html');
?>
```

But I hope this helps